# Delete style width image in inline style php

Tags: php, html, css

hello i want show paragraph with image from database.
but  i want delete inline style width image.

example :

```
   <?php $prg = "hello this is paragragph and this is image 1 
<img src='https://www.google.co.id/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' style='width:150px;heigh:150px'> 
this is text and this is image 2 
<img src='http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/HumpbackWhaleReunion_ROW11050338497_1366x768.jpg' style='width:150px;heigh:150px' ></p>";

            echo $prg; ?>
```

i want delete width image in inline style.

this code result i want like this

```
   <?php $prg = "hello this is paragragph and this is image 1 
<img src='https://www.google.co.id/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' style='heigh:150px'> 
this is text and this is image 2 
<img src='http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/HumpbackWhaleReunion_ROW11050338497_1366x768.jpg' style='heigh:150px' ></p>";

            echo $prg; ?>
```

Comment: Use style='heigh:150px;width:0'

Comment: this data from database, i can't change.

Comment: If u getting for database than try: <style>img{width:0 !important;}</style>

Comment: no no..
this my page have many img. i only want delete width image in paragraph

Comment: Than just remove using Php `str_replace("style='width:150px;heigh:150px'","style='height:150px;'",$img);

Comment: Also chk str_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here ya go - using regular expressions

```
<?php
$prg = "hello this is paragragph and this is image 1 
<img src='https://www.google.co.id/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' style='width:150px;heigh:150px'> 
this is text and this is image 2 
<img src='http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/HumpbackWhaleReunion_ROW11050338497_1366x768.jpg' style='width:150px;heigh:150px' ></p>";

echo preg_replace("/width:[0-9]+[a-z]{2};?/i",'',$prg);
?>
```

showing regex is matching
https://regex101.com/r/xE8gX7/1

Comment: No problem! Enjoy! If my answer worked for ya, accept me as the answer! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `str_replace()`

```
$prg = "hello this is paragragph and this is image 1 <img src='https://www.google.co.id/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' style='width:150px;heigh:150px'> this is text and this is image 2 <img src='http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/HumpbackWhaleReunion_ROW11050338497_1366x768.jpg' style='width:150px;heigh:150px' ></p>"; 

$prg = str_replace("style='width:150px;heigh:150px'"," style='height:150px;'",$prg);
```